# Using UITableView inside Container view for forms - how do I access the form fields?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm experimenting with using table views inside a Storyboard to build forms, but I can't figure out a simple way to access the form fields when the table is inside a container.

This is what I have:

[image: How I have my storyboard set up]

- a custom view controller (LoginController) with a Container View where the form goes
- a static UITableViewController embedded in the Container
- fields (email, password, etc.) inside cells in the UITableViewController

My question is: what's the simplest way to access the value of the email and password fields from LoginController?  There doesn't seem to be any way to link the fields to IBOutlets in the LoginController.  I could make a custom table view controller for every form I build, or do something with the segue, but that's getting too complicated. Is there any way to keep everything in the storyboard?

Comment: There are certainly ways to do this, but why would you want to? The email and password are necessary for the login, so the login view controller should handle that directly, without relying on another view controller. Why not use 2 text fields (not in a container view) instead of a table view?

Comment: Mainly for convenience - tables are an easy(?) way to make nice looking forms.  Login is a trivial example - for larger forms, forms with sections, etc., it's easy to put everything in a table and not worry about the layout.  But if getting to the data becomes difficult, that defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: I should add: this is easy if the entire form controller (LoginController) is a table view controller to start with, but not if I want the table to only take up part of the view.

Comment: @alex_c I am stuck with the same problem.Can you tell me how you solved this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a table view, then you have two choices. You can use dynamic prototypes instead of a static table, so you can add a table view directly to the login controller (and size it how you want). Or, you can do it like you are doing in your question with an embedded table view controller. In that case, you could make the login controller the delegate of the table view controller in prepareForSegue. That method would be called when the login controller is instantiated, so you can set yourself as delegate there. You would then need to define a delegate protocol in the table view controller to send the data you collect back to the delegate. Doing it this way, there's no way to set up everything in the storyboard (in terms of direct outlets, because you can't set up outlets across controllers).